# Error 3001: write xHttp.responseBody

Tags: vb.net, download

The following code downloads files from a location. It is working on my Machine but not on server. I am getting:

> Runtime Error 3001: 'Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range…'at '.write xHttp.responseBody

The below is the Code Snippet:

```
 For i = 2 To row_cnt
 Value1 = xlSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
 Value2 = xlSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value

 'MsgBox "value of i--> " & i
  Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")

xHttp.Open "GET", Value1, False, "username", "password"
xHttp.Send

With bStrm
.Type = 1 '//binary
 .Open
.write xHttp.responseBody
.savetofile Value2, 2 '//overwrite
 End With
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a file or folder permissions issue on the server.

Comment: What kind of permission? I can access, create do everything on the desired folders on the server.?

Comment: When this code runs, does it run as you, or as IIS_IUSR? If this code is for a web service, then IIS_IUSR will need permission too.

Comment: Ths is not related to permission as.. 

.Type = 2 '//TEXT
 .Open
.writeText xHttp.responseBody

this is downloading the pdf but the files are corrupted.